# Tkinter how to size fonts and keep alignment

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing an app that needs to be zoomable. Using the default system fonts, "TkDefaultFont and TkTextFont" I increase their sizes and I get the results I want sort of. The problem is after sizing the alignment is thrown off between the field label and field widget. I have tried applying update_idletasks() but it does nothing. Moving the mouse over the widget fixes the problem as see in the video. If you run the example below go the the size spinbox and change the size to view the issue.

My dev system is Linux, Desktop KDE, I don't know if this is a OS issue.

A link to a short video of the issue. 
[Video of Alignment Issue.](https://youtu.be/qrpyx2plSrQ)

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.font as tkfont

root = tk.Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(99, weight=1)


frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

cbo = ttk.Combobox(frame)
cbo.config(
    values=('Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3')
)
cbo.set(value='Test 1')

ent_var = tk.StringVar()
ent = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=ent_var)
ent_var.set('Test')


lb_size = ttk.Label(frame, text='size')
spn = ttk.Spinbox(frame,  values=tuple(range(1, 101)))

font1 = tkfont.nametofont('TkDefaultFont')
font2 = tkfont.nametofont('TkTextFont')

lbl_field_name = tk.Label(frame, text='Field Name')
lbl_field_name.grid()


def size(e):
    cfg = font1.actual()
    cfg['size'] = e.widget.get()
    font1.configure(**cfg)
    font2.configure(**cfg)


spn.bind('<<Increment>>', size)
spn.bind('<<Decrement>>', size)


cbo.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)
ent.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)
lb_size.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=tk.NSEW)
spn.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=tk.NSEW)
frame.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would help if you included a small [mcve] so that people who are trying to answer this question have a starting point.

Comment: I would but I would need to include to much of the app that that's not possible. I was hoping someone else has had the same problem and could help. All I'm doing is increasing the size of TkDefaultFont and TkTextFont, but the alignment don't happen until you mouse over the widget as see in the video.

Comment: Based on your video, all we need is an app with a couple of comboboxes, a spinbox for the font size, and enough code to make that work. I don't see why you can't provide that in your question.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm doing. I will get back when I have the example.

Comment: Update with working example.

Comment: The problem is in the widget, it's a combo box although I would think it would be the same in an entry widget.

Comment: Yes the same thing happens with an Entry widget.

Comment: I also found out the the mouse over does not affect entry widgets as the code above shows, the alignment stays the same.

Comment: Try updating the `font` property of the widgets in `size(...)` function, e.g. cbo.config(font=font1).

Comment: There is library PyQT5, have you considered using it? I think it is much easier a better, you can design ui without scripting

Comment: btw `ttk.Spinbox()` is throwing error: `AttributeError: module 'tkinter.ttk' has no attribute 'Spinbox'`. I think you mean `tk.Spinbox()`.

Comment: @Grzegorz Krug: No I want to use tkinter I do know about PyQT5, thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I have found to avoid this issue is to change the font from each entry's `configure()` method. I guess the easier way will be to put all the entries in a list, see code below.

I have also noticed that `size()` uses the previous value of the spinbox not the one after the increment/decrement. To avoid that, I suggest you to use the `command` option of the spinbox instead of the bindings to `<<Increment>>` and `<<Decrement>>` (see code below).

Finally, you do not need to retrieve the whole font settings to update the size, you can simply do `font1.configure(size=<newsize>)`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.font as tkfont

root = tk.Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(99, weight=1)


frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

entries = []  # list of all entries

cbo = ttk.Combobox(frame)
cbo.config(
    values=('Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3')
)
cbo.set(value='Test 1')
entries.append(cbo)

ent_var = tk.StringVar()
ent = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=ent_var)
ent_var.set('Test')
entries.append(ent)


def size():
    size = spn.get()  # get current spinbox's value
    font1.configure(size=size)
    font2.configure(size=size)
    for e in entries:  # update font in all entries
        e.configure(font=font2)


lb_size = ttk.Label(frame, text='size')
# use the command option to update the font size
spn = ttk.Spinbox(frame, command=size, values=tuple(range(1, 101)))  

font1 = tkfont.nametofont('TkDefaultFont')
font2 = tkfont.nametofont('TkTextFont')

lbl_field_name = ttk.Label(frame, text='Field Name')
lbl_field_name.grid()

cbo.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)
ent.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)
lb_size.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=tk.NSEW)
spn.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=tk.NSEW)
frame.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You said "use command option of the spinbox instead". I really want to use bind because I attach attributes and or variables to the widget, that are then available in the callback function. I have rewritten the code to use bind and it functions normally. I pasted the code on pastebin if you care to view how I managed to use bind.   https://pastebin.com/3JHjvZ8G

Comment: @DanielHuckson No problem, this was just a suggestion because I noticed that the previous size was used. I understand that you have other constraints coming from your project which where not relevant to this question. Thanks for sharing your solution.

Comment: Yes I found that out as well, but for some reason the call root.after(0, func) seems to fix that issue. Any idea why this is?

Comment: I just finished refactoring the code in my project with your solution and it seems it's not viable for me. I have to many widgets that need to be sized and it kills the zooming effect (getting lag). I guess I will just have to live with it the way it is until they fix the issue. Or someone else comes up with a fix without the lag!

Comment: @DanielHuckson The problem with the binding to `<<Increment/Decrement>>` is that it is called before the change of value in the spinbox occurs. By adding the call to`after()`, you execute the function just after the value change. Unfortunately, for your font issue I don't think there is any solution not involving looping over all the entries.

Comment: I would write each of these fields to sit inside of a frame so you can control width. The resizing of everything as the font changes is going to be very annoying.

Comment: Because I want the zooming effect to be as smooth as possible, I need to use the system default names ie. "TkDefaultFont, TkTextFont". The problem with this is just one thing, while zooming live the alignment of the contents does not get centered vertically. I used the solution above but this is not possible to do live I got too much lag. The best solution I have so far is to let it go out of alignment while zooming then fix it when then zooming stops.